# Rename files given them a consecutive date with Python

Tags: python, date, rename

I have 163 files:

- `image0001.png`
- `image0002.png`
- ...
- `image000163.png`

Each image correspond to a date between `01/01/2020` and `13/06/2020`, but they were created today (`01/07/2020`), so all of them have the same date metadata in Windows, which doesn't let me to get the date of creation from each file.

What I'm trying to do is to postfix the name with the corresponding date between (`01/01/2020` and `13/06/2020`). I am trying to making it using Python, but I have not succeeded.

How can I achieve that?

Comment: Please, utilize ctr+b and ctr+k for beautify your text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two modules that will let you do this without many troubles: `os`, to rename the files, and `datetime` to handle the dates. Normally, they both come included in Python by default.

Please note that you won't be able to name your files with the trailing slash character (`/`), so I used a dash instead (`-`).

Also, to make everything easier (i. e: not being necessary to work with absolute paths, `os.path.join`, `os.path.dirname`, et cetera), make sure you put this script inside the **same folder** that you have your images in.

```py
import datetime
import os


curr_date = datetime.datetime(2020, 1, 1)

for i in range(1, 164):
    file_name = f'image000{i}'
    date_str = curr_date.strftime('%d-%m-%Y')
    os.rename(file_name + '.png', f'{file_name} {date_str}.png')
    curr_date += datetime.timedelta(days=1)
```

**EDIT**

In case of the names following the pattern: `'0001', '0002', ... , '0020', ... '0100'`, you could use the `rjust()` function of the `str` class. Something as shown below. (I'm using `format()` instead of F-Strings for string interpolation, since I like it more to use it when I need to call a method or perform some operation over the object that is being iterpolated in the string)

```
file_name = 'image{}'.format(str(i).rjust(4, '0'))
```

Alternatively, if you want to stick with F-Strings, you could use the Format Specification Mini-Language:

```
file_name = f"image{i:0>4}"
```

Comment: THANKS A LOT!!

Just two things:
The first output was:

01/01/2020, 01/02/2020, ... 01/06/2020 AND THEN 02/01/2020,...02/06/2020,03/01/2020...
So I just changed the line by date_str = curr_date.strftime('%m-%d-%Y')  and it was solved!

Also I would like to know, if the names of the images were: 
image0001.png
image0020.png
...
image0163.png

How to indicate the index {i} in the file name?

Comment: Alrighty. I put the format as I did based on your example. Let me update my answer to show you how you would do it in case of the names being like you say

Comment: Thanks very much, it was just, perfect!